Why is maximizing the Cox partial likelihood meaningful
So the likelihood of seeing our data in survival analysis is (assuming simple case of no censorship and no ties):
P(first death happened at time t1) x P(first death was patient p1 | previous information) x P(second death happened at time t2 | previous information) * ...

Now as far as I understand in Cox regression we separate out the terms into two distinct products. One product has all the terms of the form
P(n-th death happened at time t_n | previous information)

And the other product collects the terms of the from
P(n-th death was patient p_n | previous information)

And then the magical part happens. We say assume the hazard function at time t given covariates x is some baseline hazard times exp(<beta, x>) and that all the patients' times of death are completely independent.
Then we can rewrite the latter product of terms (dubbed the Cox partial likelihood) in terms of just beta and x (baseline hazard cancels out regardless of its form).
Finally we can then choose beta that maximizes the Cox partial likelihood.
That is all well and good, but my question is why do we think the beta that maximizes this part of the full product is meaningful? By doing this we are determining the model that maximizes the likelihood of our data appearing in the order that it did. Not at all taking into consideration the times of the events.
I have seen arguments that beta doesn't effect the the terms in non-Cox partial likelihood (the terms of the former form) so one can disregard them (essentially arguing that the beta that maximizes the actual likelihood is the same as the beta that maximizes the Cox partial likelihood). I take problem with that argument.
As I see it beta clearly affects the hazard for each patient at any given point in time. And the P(n-th death happened at time t_n | previous information) very clearly depends on the hazard of each patient from time t_(n-1) up to t_n.
So as I see it the setting of beta that maximizes the Cox partial likelihood could be arbitrarily different than the beta that maximizes the actual full likelihood.
I assume that I am obviously lacking in understanding given that this is considered a very robust model and is utilized heavily in medical research. But can some explain to me what I am missing from a mathematical view point?
